# c++: Extern with auto fails to compile

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```
#include <vector>
extern std::vector<int> const my_vector;
auto const my_vector = std::vector<int>{};
```

It fails to compile on gcc but it works on clang since 6.0.0:

```
[x86-64 gcc 8.1 #1] error: conflicting declaration 'const auto my_vector'
```

Is this a gcc bug or a violation of the spec?